# hibernate access object class inside an object class

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, netbeans, jdbc

i'm on a final project now and making web app using hibernate.
my topic is recipe web site, and i have to show all the likers for a recipe

here's my pojo class for likes (not including the constructor and getter setter here to make it short code)

```
 public class Likes  implements java.io.Serializable {

 private LikesId id;
 private Member member;
 private Resep resep;
 private Integer likes;

public Likes() {
}
}
```

here's my pojo class for likes id (not including the getter setter here to make it short code)

```
 public class LikesId  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private String idResep;
 private String idMember;

public LikesId() {
}

public LikesId(String idResep, String idMember) {
   this.idResep = idResep;
   this.idMember = idMember;
}
}
```

now here is my method to show all likers for a recipe

```
public ArrayList<Likes> getAllLikes(String kode_resep)
{
    this.session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    ArrayList<Likes> hasil = null;;
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Query q = session.createQuery("from Likes join LikesID on ()='"+kode_resep+"'");
    hasil = (ArrayList<Likes>) q.list();

    session.close();
    return hasil;

}
```

the error when i run this method is:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: **unexpected AST
>   node: ( near line 1, column 35 [from model.Likes where
>   Likes.getId().getIdResep()='R001'**]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from Likes l where l.id.idResep = :code_resep");
q.setParameter("code_resep",kode_resep);
q.list();
```